# Python Pandas - Pivot table aggregating wrong column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (dfFF):

```
    Sector  Country    Currency    Amount    Year
0   Charity    UK         GBP      328163    2018
1   Public     UK         GBP      120480    2017
2   Public     UK         GBP      123086    2017
3   Public     UK         GBP      125198    2017
4   Public     UK         GBP      1502793   2017
5   Public     UK         GBP      249999    2016
```

And I want to pivot it so I have `Country` as the rows and `Sector` on the columns with the `Amount` summed.

I use the code:

```
dfFFB = pd.pivot_table(dfFF, index=['Country'], columns=['Sector'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

And I get this:

```
    Year
Sector     Charity     Public
Country     
   UK       4036       28234
```

Which is summing the `year`, not the `amount`.

How would I force it to sum the `Amount`?

Comment: Need define parameter `values` like `dfFFB = pd.pivot_table(dfFF, index='Country', columns='Sector', values='Amount', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`

Comment: add `values` argument to `pd.pivot_table(...)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was googling but was obviously asking the wrong question. Thank you!